# Robust DuplicateFreeQ for numerical data

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, code-request

I am looking for a fast and robust `DuplicateFreeQ` equivalent for numerical data. Floating point numbers should normally be compared with some tolerance, as `Equal` and `SameQ` do.

Has anyone implemented such a function and considered all the edge cases?

Here's a slow but simple implementation to get the ball rolling:

```
numericDuplicateFreeQ[data_] := 
  With[{sorted = Sort@N[data]},
    Not[Or @@ MapThread[Equal, {Most[sorted], Rest[sorted]}]]
  ]
```

The function should be capable of at least the following:

- If there are any two 'equal' list elements, return `False`. Otherwise, return `True`.
- Work with any `ArrayQ[#, _, NumericQ]&` data (although a version that only works with lists of numbers is already useful).
- Compare like `Equal` does (or in a similar way), with adjustable tolerance (see `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``).
- It must work with at least machine precision numbers. Ideally, it would work with any exact, arbitrary precision or machine precision numbers, but this may be more difficult to implement.

Comment: Why is this difficult? The data may contain exact or floating point numbers, equality needs to be handled properly. The data may contain machine precision or arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: Even if we restrict the data to machine precision floating point only, we need to compute some sort of *relative* difference. There is an edge case for near-zero numbers.  Better, we need to compute a difference in ulps. Doing that *with good performance* is not trivial.

Comment: I haven't done any performance tests, but maybe something that uses `LengthWhile` and `Sort` would work? E.g., `Block[{x}, LengthWhile[Sort[data], Not[TrueQ[x == (x = #)]] &]]` (and then testing if it's the same length as `data`, of course).

Comment: Never mind, `LengthWhile` is actually slower than `MapThread` here. I can beat `MapThread` by about a factor of 2 on machine precision arrays with either `Split` or a compiled `Do` loop (using `Catch`/`Throw` or `Break` to abort once a duplicate is found). That's the best I managed. A rather substantial portion of the time goes into sorting the list, but I don't know of a good method that can skip the sorting step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is anything wrong with `OrderedQ[Sort@N@data, Less]`?

```
SeedRandom[0]
data = RandomReal[1, 10^6];

Internal`$EqualTolerance = 2;
OrderedQ[Sort@N@data, Less] // RepeatedTiming

Internal`$EqualTolerance = 7;
OrderedQ[Sort@N@data, Less] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.3581, True}
>
> {0.1785, False}
> ```

Comment: This is actually pretty good!

Comment: One issue is that it only uses machine precision. Now that is not an issue for the specific application I had in mind, but it would be nice to handle arbitrary precision numbers too. That can actually be done by removing `N` and replacing `Less` with `TrueQ @* Less`, at the cost of a 2x slowdown.  The assumption is still that we have `NumericQ` data.

Answer (score 5):

This has 0 problems, but for vectors maybe you could do something like:

```
dupFreeQ[d_, tol_] := With[{s = Sort @ N @ d},
    FreeQ[0] @ Chop[Rest[s]/Most[s] - 1, tol]
]
```

Example:

```
data = RandomReal[{1, 1 + 10^-3}, 10^6];

dupFreeQ[data, 10^-14] //AbsoluteTiming
numericDuplicateFreeQ[data] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.246441, False}
>
> {0.525652, False}

Adjusting the tolerance:

```
dupFreeQ[data, 5 10^-16] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.274373, True}

Another idea is to use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest):

```
Nearest[N @ data -> "Index", data] //OrderedQ //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.278319, True}

vs:

```
data = RandomReal[{1, 1 + 10^-5}, 10^6];

Nearest[N @ data -> "Index", data] //OrderedQ //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.519298, False}

although this will be slow if there are lots of duplicates, and there is no tolerance control. On the other hand, I think this kind of approach will be more robust for higher order arrays.